# iPhone do not allow input text to be writable for the HTML form

Tags: html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a website (check below image for the URL) in the home page it has a inquiry form. It's made with Bootstrap 3 some CSS with Contact Form 7.

I have tried this page in so many online iPhone tester and the Form is working fine. But in the real iPhone you cannot able to click on text box, so you cannot able type.

I search a lot cleaned the form and checked the code and did not find any solution.

Tried some thing like this

```
-webkit-appearance: none !important;
-webkit-text-fill-color:#880000 !important;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code and possibly create a fiddle that replicates the problem?

Comment: its in wordpress do not know how to put it in fiddle but in desktop browser its working fine. <768 the form in iPhone not writeable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input is wrapped in a span, that has no length or width to it. Try giving that a display of block, and see if that helps! The class is "wpcf7-form-control-wrap"

Comment: Ok I have done it could you plz try from your end? I do not have iPhone

Comment: I am able to type in all text fields from my iPhone 5.